# Riemann Upper and Lower Sums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation

Suppose $f$ is defined on $I = [0,10]$ as follows: $f(x) = N$ if $N-1 \leq x < N$, $N$ is an integer.

Let $P = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\} \in \prod(P)$

Find $S[f,P]$ and $s[f,P]$

If $P^* = \{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$  then what are $S[f,P^*]$ and $s[f,P^*]$?

Not only am I confused about how this function is defined, but I am also utterly lost on how to compute these upper and lower sums. Any sort of direction would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $P^*$ the partition points are $x_k = 10*k/5 = 2k$ for $k = 0, 1, \ldots,5$.

For $x \in [2k-2,2k-1]$ we have $f(x) = 2k-1$. Also $f(2k) = 2k+1$.

Hence, on $[2(k-1),2k] = [2k-2,2k-1] \cup [2k-1,2k]$ we have $\inf f = 2k-1$ and $\sup f = 2k +1.$

The upper and lower sums are

$$S(f,P^*) = \sum_{k=1}^5 (2k+1)(2k - 2(k-1)) =2\sum_{k=1}^5 (2k+1), \\ s(f,P^*) = \sum_{k=1}^5 (2k-1)(2k - 2(k-1)) =2\sum_{k=1}^5 (2k-1). $$

I'll leave it to you to evaluate those sums.

Comment: @RedShift: You're welcome.